# Webform CiviCRM - Update Recurring Payment Profile

Tags: webform-civicrm, recurring-contributions

Let's say in 2018 someone uses the webform and creates a membership and a recurring payment - ongoing - for $5 at a certain membership level.

Let's say in 2019, they want to upgrade their membership level. They login and use the same form to choose the next level up and want to pay $10 ongoing. Great. They submit the form.

What happens to the first profile? Does the recurring profile get upgraded or disabled?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a new recurring profile is created leaving the old one intact. We had similar issue where people upgraded from and to auto-renew membership from online and they had 2 recurring in progress i.e payment was deducted twice unless we had to manually cancel the subscription in payment processor for the old one.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to patch the module or use a rule of some form to get the expected behavior? We know the membership when loading the form, and we also know that it's tied to a recurring profile. The functionality should update the details of the recurring profile with the new data, or disable it and create a new one? Right?